# Admob orientation support in Android

Tags: android, orientation, admob, ads

I'm new to Android platform and currently considering Admob integration into my application. I have two questions regarding this:

1. I've managed to integrate Admob test ads into my app but don't know how to get real ads in it. Despite setting testing="false", it's still showing me the test ads only.
2. It's not supporting orientation in landscape mode. I read in a post that Admob doesn't support orientation but the post was quite old. I want to know whether it's supported now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first question, you have to register on AdMob web site to get a client id. Then use this client id in your app. This way you will get the real ads.

Comment: What about the changes in code? What should be replaced in place of:          AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] {                 
                AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR 
        });

Comment: You use TEST_EMULATOR for test ads only. If you have a valid client id, don't use TEST_EMULATOR. Instead fetch the ads from server by using the requestFreshAd(); method.

Comment: By client id, do you mean publisher id that we obtain upon registering our application?

Comment: Sorry buddy, I confused it. You're right, its publisher id. We've to add it in a meta tag in manifest file.

Comment: I dont know but after removing AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] { AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR }); ads have stopped appearing in my app despite the fact that I have included requestFreshAd() method. Also, can you answer my 2nd question?

Comment: Please check the Logcat output. There exist the entries about AdMob. Those will tell you about the problem. And sorry I've no solution about your second problem because I'm still facing the same.

Comment: Let me know the results if you progress further.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must to have register on Admob web site to google account, if success full signup follow these steps.

Click on Monetize-> +Monetize new app -> select an app -> select ad format and name ad unit -> View setup instruction.

after completed these steps to got a Ad unit ID: ca-app-pub-555555545345/43545345(like this and copy it)

and put on in you xml file.

and don't use test id statement in your java code.

This is way to get real ads in your app.